# Camel consumers still get new messages when shutting down

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Camel 2.16.1. When shutting down, Camel's consumers still accept new messages. Is there any way to force consumers stop immediately. There is same problem here: [Camel ShutdownStrategy: Inflight Messages do not decrease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396317/camel-shutdownstrategy-inflight-messages-do-not-decrease)

I create a testcase for this issue:

```
    public class GracefulShutdownTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    public class ThreadStopContext implements Runnable {
        private CamelContext context;

        public ThreadStopContext(CamelContext context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("------start shutdown....");
                context.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Sender implements Runnable {
        private ProducerTemplate template;

        public Sender(ProducerTemplate template) {
            this.template = template;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            template().sendBody("direct:start", "test");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shutdownTest() throws Exception {
        context().setTracing(true);
        getMockEndpoint("mock:endpoint").expectedMessageCount(0);
        getMockEndpoint("mock:deadletterEndpoint").expectedMessageCount(1);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStopContext(context()));
        thread.start();
        Thread threadSender1 = new Thread(new Sender(template()));
        threadSender1.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("-------------------second message-----------------------------");
        Thread threadSender2 = new Thread(new Sender(template()));
        threadSender2.start();
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:deadletter")
                        .logHandled(true));

                from("direct:start").process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("----------start sleep....");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        System.out.println("----------end sleep....");
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                });

                from("direct:deadletter")
                        .startupOrder(1)
                        .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("----message at deadletter----");
                    }
                })
                        .to("mock:deadletterEndpoint");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When run the test case, we can see the number of inflight exchanges is increase after starting to graceful shutdown:

```
Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete
.....
Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading source code of Defaultshutdownstrategy class, I found out that when shutting down consumers, Camel prefer suspend than shutdown. That mean if a consumer support suspend, it will execute suspend method, then put the consumer to defer list to shutdown later. Some consumers(direct, RabbitMQ) have empty suspend() method, then they are still get new messages like in Defer mode

Comment: Yes its expected with direct, as is internal component - externals like file / jms can suspend. And rabbit in next release.